# CSS3 filter: image overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with my CSS code. When I am using `filter:gray;` in my CSS stylesheet, my black/white pictures are overlapping menu. When the pictures have no filter effect menu is behaving correctly.

[image: Filter applied on the right side of the foto]

CSS:

```
img.images {
  filter: gray; 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

CSS of MENU:

```
#navigationMenu{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    width:175px;
    height:680px;
    list-style:none;
    border-right: 1px dotted #ffff66;

}


#navigationMenu li{
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    height:95px;
    padding:4px;
    width:95px;
}

#navigationMenu span{
    width:0;
    left: 95px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top:12px;

    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:70px;
}

#navigationMenu a{
    height:95px;
    width:95px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML of MENU:

```
<ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="home" href="#">
            <span>Home</span></a>       
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="about" href="#">
            <span>Virtual Tuning</span></a>         
    </li>

    <li>
         <a class="services" href="#">
            <span>Drawings</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

HTML:

```
<img class="images" src="images/virtual/seat.jpg">
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: A stylesheet is nothing without corresponding HTML. Can you post some please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having complete code, it is hard to tell for sure, but it looks like this might be IE only kind of issue. If that's the case, try using complete `progid` instead of `gray`, like this:

```
img.images {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1); 
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)";
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

Another idea would be to play with z-index css property after filter.

Comment: I tried to complete my code by what you wrote but I dont see any difference... Thanks for trying though! I am going to google some z-index info :)

Comment: Is it IE only issue? 
Also, that first thing I would try is to set zIndex on the panel that shows "Virtual Tuning" popup.

Comment: It is not IE problem only.. I tried to add z-indes: 10; and it WORKED! Thanks for help